# Complications with carrying variables through forms

Tags: php

I have a database created in phpmyadmin that I have synced up to a php page, which is meant to show some information, but not all, unless you click a button which takes you to a more in depth description of one row of the table.

```
if($result->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

        echo "<tr>\n";
        echo "<td>".$row["VAR"]."</td>\n";
        echo "<td>".$row["VAR2"]."</td>\n";
        echo "<td>".$row["VAR3"]."</td>\n";
        $more = '<td><form role = "form" class = "form-inline" action = 
        "page2.php" method = "get"><input type = "submit" value = "More"> 
        </form></td>';
        echo $more;
        echo "</tr>\n";
        }
}
```

The while loop ensures that the "More" button appears on each row of the table, as instructed. However, when I try and pass the variable through to page2.php, it gives me an undefined index error. The main goal is just to query the data so only the row in which the button was pressed is shown on page2.php.

```
$sql  = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `VAR` = '$getVAR'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

I've tried numerous $_GET commands to try and get the specific VAR to the next page but nothing seems to work. Does anyone have any ideas? TIA

Comment: Your form contains only one input element (the submit button), and that doesn't even have a name ... so what data do you expect to find in $_GET exactly ...?

Comment: It makes rather little sense to use a form for this in the first place. Use a normal link, append the parameter you want to transport to the URL you put into the `href` attribute of that link ... and _format_ it via CSS to look like a button, if that's the actual purpose here.

Comment: I guess you need to change here for example: `action = "page2.php?getVAR='.urlencode($row["VAR"]).'"   method=get` That is just to start...

Comment: How would you propose I manage to single out the selected row within the form?

Comment: I always thought it's suppposed to be `method="post"` not `method="get"`, But judging by the comments i was wrong

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin they are alternative: their behaviour is different and there are situation where one can be preferrable compared to the other

Comment: you're open to SQL injection - I'd address asap :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some issues on the FORM related to the information you send: mainly you miss to pass the value of the row for which you want to see more:

```
$more = '<td><form class = "form-inline" action = "page2.php" method = "get">
        <input type="hidden" name="id_value" value="'.$row['VAR'].'"> 
        <input type = "submit" value = "More"> 
        </form></td>';
```

Change the `$row` variable to the one you want to pass as parameter for the query (it's unclear from your question)

Comment: Thanks for the help, this worked a charm! Tried playing about with hidden variables beforehand must have just been overcomplicating things

Answer (score 0):

Set the value of the value of the submit button to `$row["VAR"]`, add a name attribute. Try this:

```
if($result->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

        echo "<tr>\n";
        echo "<td>".$row["VAR"]."</td>\n";
        echo "<td>".$row["VAR2"]."</td>\n";
        echo "<td>".$row["VAR3"]."</td>\n";
        $more = '<td><form role = "form" class = "form-inline" action = 
        "page2.php" method = "get"><input name="VAR" type = "submit" value = "'.$row["VAR"].'"> 
        </form></td>';
        echo $more;
        echo "</tr>\n";
        }
}
```

Then you add this for the detail page:

```
$getVAR = $_GET["VAR"];
$sql  = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `VAR` = '$getVAR'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```